# Referring to textbox name in click event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to find a way to automatically refer to a textbox name within its click event.  The name will be used in a sub called by the event code.  I know that it can be hard coded, but I have many textboxes and would prefer to have general purpose code.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Yeah, I should have typed 'label' instead of 'textbox' - sorry.  Anyway, I'd like to be able to use a simple bit of code like:

```
Private Sub lbl_Charges_Click()
    tabPage (me.activecontrol.name)
End Sub
```

Obviously, the `activecontrol` method does not work on labels. The code I'm calling is:

```
Private Sub tabPage(page As String)
    page = Mid(page, 5)
    Echo False
    Me.tab_Menu.Pages("pag_" & page).SetFocus
    Me.tab_Menu.Visible = True
    Me.lbl_Hide.SetFocus
    Echo True
End Sub
```

The reason I'm doing all of this is that I'm trying to find a way to get rid of all of the flicker associated with this (tab menu and label backgrounds are transparent)  The `echo` method will take care of the flicker with the tab menu pages, but doesn't help with the command buttons.

TIA

Comment: please provide the code youre using at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveControl`:

```
Call SomeClickFunction(Me.ActiveControl.Name)
```

or, to pass the control itself:

```
Call SomeClickFunction(Me.ActiveControl)
```